# Using a pointer to a parser in boost::spirit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Basically I'm doing an expression parser. As I'm in need of as good as possible performance, and according to the documentation construction of a grammar can be rather slow, I'd like to reuse the grammar and bind the symbol table just before parsing. As the client of the grammar is likely to have a symbol table that's constructed and maintained ahead of parsing, I'd ideally like to avoid copying of the actual table as well which leads me to the following code ( simplified ) for translating terms:

```
qi::symbols< char, double >* m_Symbols;
qi::rule< Iterator, double(), ascii::space_type > m_Val;

m_Val = qi::int_[ _val = boost::phoenix::static_cast_< double >( boost::spirit::_1 ) ] | qi::double_ | m_Symbols;
```

The problem here is m_Symbols. What I'd like is to m_Val to hold m_Symbols by reference, as when we're binding the symbol table I'm naturally modifying the pointer, which I presume can somehow be solved by the use of boost::phoenix::ref? But the larger problem is that I can't seem to use pointer to parsers when compositing new parser. Using dereference in the expression dereferences m_Symbols straight away, which is unwanted, I want to delay the dereferencing to parse time.

Comment: This really seems like the wrong approach to reducing the number of grammar instances. Why not just have a static/singleton instance of the grammar and make it non-copyable?

Comment: Sadly I'd still have to bind the symbol table before parsing, which would result in the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe a simple

```
qi::symbols<char, double>* m_Symbols;
qi::rule<Iterator, double(), ascii::space_type> m_Val;

m_Val = qi::int_ | qi::double_ | qi::lazy(*m_Symbols);
```

should do what you need. The `lazy` parser (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auxiliary/lazy.html)) evaluates its argument (repeatedly) at parse time only.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, awesome with an expert to help out! Sadly I've already tried that solution and it would seem qi::lazy() isn't very happy to accept that expression. I get the following error from MSVC 2008: 1><deleted>/main.cpp(75) : error C2784: 'proto::terminal<boost::phoenix::actor<Eval>>::type boost::spirit::lazy(const boost::phoenix::actor<Eval> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const boost::phoenix::actor<Eval> &' from 'boost::spirit::qi::symbols<Char,T>'
Which leads me to believe m_Symbols gets dereferenced before passed to lazy()?

Comment: It would seem the following does the trick: qi::lazy( *boost::phoenix::val( boost::phoenix::ref( m_Symbols ) ) ) . Val acting as a wrapper to deffer the dereference, ref to make sure that the pointer isn't copied.